# Prevent data reset while hiding the div

Tags: javascript, html

I have one HTML page. It has 3  tag contains below details. 
(when Form is shown other 2 are hidden & likewise.)

```
1. One Form 
2. Calculated Values from Form
3. Summary
```

After form filling, Whenever I click on "proceed" button, a JS function is called & result is calculated. I want to fill this result in summary table fields. & every time "proceed" button is clicked new values should be added to old values & set new values to that field. 
One time, I have put values in summary, but whenever I click on "show form" & summary gets hidden, the table gets reset. What should be the problem? I want to use only js & html.
What should I do ? 
Help..

Comment: Can you share your code please? Without the code, we can't do much!

Comment: Hiding a DIV doesn't do anything to the contents. Are you sure you're not submitting the form? You need to return `false` from the `onclick` handler or call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent normal form submission.

Comment: Hmmm..Yes... actually in <a> tag I put both href n onlick So data was resetting. I Solved it. :) Thanks!